# Scala implicit parameter null when implicit val defined after method call

Tags: scala, implicit

Consider:

```scala
object implicitnull extends App {
  mymethod

  implicit val arg = "foo"

  def mymethod(implicit arg: String) = {
    arg.size
  }
}
```

This does not cause any compilation error, however, at runtime results in `NullPointerException` coming from `arg.size`.

Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: this can be incredibly annoying when stacking traits

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it's the intended behavior due to the way Scala constructs classes and initializes them. Consider this example:

```
scala> class A {
     |   f
     | 
     |   implicit val arg = "foo"
     | 
     |   def f(implicit arg: String) = {
     |     println(arg)
     |   }
     | }
defined class A

scala> class B {
     |   f(arg)
     | 
     |   val arg = "foo"
     | 
     |   def f(implicit arg: String) = {
     |     println(arg)
     |   }
     | }
defined class B

scala> class C {
     |   implicit val arg = "foo"
     | 
     |   f
     | 
     |   def f(implicit arg: String) = {
     |     println(arg)
     |   }
     | }
defined class C

scala> new A
null
res0: A = A@67d3caf

scala> new B
null
res1: B = B@3f2c5ad4

scala> new C
foo
res2: C = C@177bdd23
```

At the moment the function `f` is invoked in class `C` the value has been initialized, while in class `B` it has been not initialized yet. Class `A` is exactly the same as class `B` - the only difference is that Scala passes the `arg` implicitly in `A`.

It's a little bit confusing because this code is doing 2 things - it's declaring member variables and executing constructor code. If you take class `B` for example, `val arg` would be declared at the point where `f` is called, but not initialized yet. `val arg = "foo"` does the initialization. Once you translate this to Java it becomes more obvious:

```
public class B {

    void f(String arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }

    String arg; // also acts as final in Scala

    public B() {
        f(arg);
        arg = "foo";
    }
}
```

Using `lazy val` or correct initialization order will help to fix it:

```
scala> class B {
     |   f(arg)
     | 
     |   lazy val arg = "foo"
     | 
     |   def f(implicit arg: String) = {
     |     println(arg)
     |   }
     | }
defined class B

scala> new B
foo
res3: B = B@3f9ac6e6
```

Comment: You get a warning in 2.11. You can make it `lazy val` to fix it.

Comment: Updated my answer to include lazy val example

Comment: things do get weird if you use traits and more complex scenarios. One other fix is to use `def` when appropriate.

Comment: Why wouldn't it trigger a compilation error? It's obvious that there's no meaningful implicit value defined yet for the call, yet it compiles fine.

Comment: Well technically it's defined but not assigned/initialized.

Comment: With respect to the warning in 2.11 - the compiler can miss this in more complex cases, which still produce NullPointerExceptions later. You can enable scalac option `-Xcheckinit` to have this detected earlier at runtime, which can be much better than only seeing it when the null is first used.